# How to give validation to registration page in phonegap Android like we see in websites?

Tags: android, validation, cordova-2.0.0

Hi I have created an registration page I want to give validation to it like the one we normally see in the websites Means if any field is blank it should show it in red with message not like we normally use dialog box or alert can any one tell how to do this.I am not using form to create pages i used div.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use javascript to validate your textbox registration like

```
$('#btnReg').click(function(){
      if($('#textField').val().length==0){
           // show you massage in div here
           // like this
           $('#MsgError').html("error msg");
           // or use alert
           alert("error msg");
      }
})
```

Comment: i used but its a simple which i know I want validation that we see on the websites while registration a div to open below the the text fields and change the color of the fields like LiveValidation.com

Comment: oh, you can use event onkeyup or onkeydown via javascript or jquery ..
i thing that right way for create validation like http://livevalidation.com/  I hope solved :D

Comment: hey thanks for reply I used juery validationengine.js its working fine but the problem is i had use collapsible and its not apply to fields which are present inside collapsible if collapsible is false its applying validation to it can you tell what i can do to provide validation to collapsible if it true.